# Synchronize Assets with AWS

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic

I'm currently using EE 2.7.3 and Assets 2.2.2 with AWS (Amazon Web Services), which works beautifully, however when I removed a few files off AWS, the files are still visible after weeks on my EE install.  Is there a way to resynchronize Assets and AWS so that the files I deleted off AWS are no longer being shown in Assets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you pressed "Updated Indexes" in the main Assets module screen (rather than the field type)?